# jquery ajax error json response

Tags: ajax, jquery, xmlhttprequest, response

i have jquery global error event set, like following:

```
 $("#message_alert").ajaxError(function(event, XMLHttpRequest, settings, thrownError){
    ajax_error(XMLHttpRequest);
 });
```

and ajax_error method gets the XMLHttpRequest parameter totally fine init. now the request which XMLHttpRequest gets, it also have json data from the backend in XMLHttpRequest.responseText

now i want to know, how can i parse this json data, i tried doing

```
eval("var request = "+XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
```

which for some reason was working fine, but dose not work anymore and i know for sure that data is getting back to ajax response. maybe something im doing wrong.. well firebug shows following error from it, i dont know what im doing wrong

Error:

```
missing ; before statement
http://basit.io.im/javascript/global.js
Line 127
```

btw this is the same eval line number. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried -

```
eval("var request = XMLHttpRequest.responseText");
```

That should fix the error you are getting.

Comment: thank you, but i think error is something else. not related javascript.. stupid me :(

Comment: really? even though the eval statement is on line 127 of global.js or did I misunderstand? If you have it live anywhere I can take look if you want?